# Which sounds correct

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammar-myths

I’m having some trouble deciding which one should I use:

> He doesn’t get mad **anymore** when I don’t reply to his text

or

> He doesn’t get mad when I don’t reply to his text **anymore**

Should **anymore** be used at the end of the sentence, or does it sound natural to use it in the middle?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way.
Anymore is referring to what he does: "He doesn't get mad anymore."

It's true, it could mean this even in the second way, as if it said: "
"He doesn't get mad (when I don't reply to his text) anymore."

But, the second way could also have the word "anymore" responding to your action, i.e. not responding to the text.

Then the sentence would mean something like:
"I don't respond to his texts anymore and he doesn't get mad."

Assuming you want the word "anymore" to modify what HE does, not what YOU do, it's less confusing to put it in the middle.